# sql - how to use distinct on two columns in union query

Tags: sql

I would like to perform a "distinct" on the following columns but cannot seem to get the formatting right:

C_TYP_SYS_IDV and I_SYS_IDV

any ideas?

THANKS!

```
create volatile table dt as (
SELECT 

            gcv.I_SYS_IDV,
             gcv.i_pln,
             gcv.c_typ_cov,
             gcv.d_eff,
             gcv.d_eff_pln,
             gcv.c_sta,
            gcv.d_sta,
            gcv.c_mde_bft_fst,
            gcv.a_bft_fst,
            gcv.c_mde_bft_sec,
             gcv.a_bft_sec,
            gcv.c_mde_bft_trd,
             gcv.a_bft_trd,
             gcv.p_cre_hom,
             gcv.c_cl_rsk,
             gpv.c_val,
             gpv.i_val,
             gcv.c_pol


            FROM Pearl_P.tltc906_gcv gcv,
             pearl_p.tltc912_gpv gpv

              WHERE  gcv.i_pln > 0
            AND gcv.i_pln = gpv.i_pln
            and gpv.i_prv = '36'
            and gcv.c_pol between 'lac100001' and 'lac100004'

         UNION

             SELECT
             gcv.I_SYS_IDV,
             gcv.i_pln,
             gcv.c_typ_cov,
             gcv.d_eff,
             gcv.d_eff_pln,
             gcv.c_sta,
             gcv.d_sta,
             gcv.c_mde_bft_fst,
             gcv.a_bft_fst,
             gcv.c_mde_bft_sec,
             gcv.a_bft_sec,
             gcv.c_mde_bft_trd,
             gcv.a_bft_trd,
             gcv.p_cre_hom,
             gcv.c_cl_rsk,
             gcv.c_pol,
             gpv.i_val,
              ''

        FROM Pearl_P.tltc906_gcv gcv,
        pearl_p.tltc912_gpv gpv


            where NOT EXISTS(
            SELECT 1
            FROM pearl_p.tltc906_gcv gcv,
             pearl_p.tltc912_gpv gpv

            WHERE  gcv.i_pln > 0
            AND gcv.i_pln = gpv.i_pln
            and gpv.i_prv = '36'
            )
        ) with data 
 PRIMARY INDEX (i_sys_idv)
 on commit preserve rows;
```

Comment: `DISTINCT` is applied across all the columns returned by a query. It cannot be applied independently to individual columns.

Comment: I don't even see C_TYP_SYS_IDV in the SELECT statements.

Comment: As JNK said below use the group by function. Check out http://www.sql-tutorial.com/sql-group-by-sql-tutorial/

Answer (score 4):

You can't do `DISTINCT` on just a few fields out of your list.

Those `DISTINCT` values represent rows.  If you want to only use those `DISTINCT` rows, you need to use `GROUP BY` clause.  Can you explain further what you are after?